# Removing 2 inch water line cost

Tags: water, pipe

I recently purchased a home on 12 acres, the previous owner installed 2 inch water pipe and had 5 connections around the property. It sounded great when I heard about it, but when I was informed that the water company charges a fee of $200 per month flat fee I'm not so thrilled. I've never used them these connections and I realize it's mainly Incase of fire but our brush is cleared and there's cement all around the home. I'm wondering is it possible to down size to the normal 3/4 inch pipe I believe most homes have, and if so what will it cost. Any advice is appreciated, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Ask your water company (and also  if there's any other way to reduce the monthly cost) - we are not them, so we really have no way of knowing what it will cost you.

Comment: Why would you want to reduce the pipe's diameter? Is there a financial incentive / reward to use 3/4" instead of 2" pipe?

Comment: @gatorback -- I think he's getting smacked by the water utility with a big bill for having a 2" service

Comment: Who is your water utility, and is the 2" incoming service to your property an all-purpose service that serves both your private fire main and domestic plumbing, or just the fire loop? Also, you want a 1" *minimum* service line coming into your house, and probably larger *anyway* in order to support residential fire sprinklers....

Comment: Asking about cost is off topic. We don't know where in the world you live, and even if we did, it's unlikely any of us would know the going rates there. Even if someone knew that, it wouldn't be useful info for the next person to come along because they're likely not your next door neighbor.